# how can i avoid retyping the same thing repitiously in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, fortran77

I have a lengthy program with several variables i want to check up on periodically.
rather than typing

```
print var1 
print var2
print var2
```

and so on, ho can I either get  output for multiple variables from one print 
(I tried `print var1, var2, var3` but that didn't work.)

or

How can I write my own function to do the same thing as repetitiously typing print for each available?

is there any easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close enough

```
print (var1, var2, ...)
```

Incidentally, you can use `p` as a shorthand for `print`:

```
p (var1, var2, ...)
```

If you simply want to monitor those variables for changes, then you need to *watch* them:

```
watch var1
watch var2
```

This way, any time the value of `var1` etc. changes, GDB will notify you and print old and new value.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but what you are looking for is probably [display command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Auto-Display.html#Auto-Display).

Do:

```
display var1
display var2
display var3
```

Then just debug as usual and the values will be printed whenever debugger stops.

If you need to do this in many session you can write command to a script and *source* it in gdb.

Comment: display looks like print to me. but print I can type with p, where d, offers to delete my breakpoints which isn't what i want.  is there any difference between display and print?

Comment: Yes, display will show variable values whenever debugger suspends (not only once like print).